# Trying to write count query loop based on a different table printing

Tags: php, mysql, sql, group-by, count

I have two tables:

```
access(name, id, check, key)

events(name, key, event_name)
```

I am trying to print some things from these tables into a php/html table with these columns:

```
name, key, event_name, access count
```

My trouble being I would like each event to display the "count" of access rows that have the same key.

Event table example:

```
name  key  event_name
test  1  first
joe  2  second
```

And the access table...

```
name  id  check  key
test  123  yes  1
test  1235  yes  1
joe  175  yes  2
joe  852  yes  2
test  5843  yes  1
test  123455  yes  1
```

The resulting table I am hoping to look like this:

```
name  key  event_name  access count
test  1  first  4
joe  2  second  2
```

Does anybody know how to do this? I've gotten to this but it obviously doesn't work because the key isn't given to the inner select query...

```
select event_name, name, key, 
       (SELECT COUNT(key) FROM access WHERE key=key AND name=name) 
from event;
```

Thank you to anyone who takes a look and might have any ideas! I've been staring at this and w3schools for hours

Answer (score 2, accepted):

At present your subquery will return a count of all rows as it is not correlated to the main query, so both occurrences of `key` in `key=key` will refer to the same column and the expression will always be true (likewise for `name`). To correlate the subquery, add table references:

```
select event_name, name, key, 
       (SELECT COUNT(key) FROM access a WHERE a.key=e.key AND a.name=e.name) AS `access count`
from event e
```

Comment: Thank you @Nick for the explanation. That makes a lot of sense, specifying which key is which and all. I modified my query, and when I run it within HeidiSQL, I am getting the results I wanted. For some reason when I copy/paste the exact query into my php code, the table is filling the correct values for everything but the counts, which now display as "1" in each of the two cells, instead of the counts "2" and "4". Problem for another night for me! Appreciate the help.

Comment: Turns out I just needed a good nights rest. The "PHP problem" I had was because I was entering test data into my hosted database, not the local one I setup for testing, therefore giving me the false issue that the output I was seeing was wrong. *facepalm*

Comment: @Amarotica been there, done that! I'm glad it was something simple...

Answer (score 1):

You can also get the same results with a join and aggregattion:

```
select e.name, e.key, e.event_name, count(*) access_count
from event e
left join access a on a.key = e.key and a.name = e.name
group by e.name, e.key, e.event_name
```